# flask: error passing variables to javascript

Tags: javascript, flask, ascii, jinja2

I'm building a flask app and I need to pass a variable created on the python back-end to javascript on the front-end to keep track of certain parameters. However, I'm encountering a strange encoding problem, Here's an example below outlining the python back-end, the rendered Jinja2 template front-end, and the error displayed in the Chrome console.

app.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def send_name():
    name = ["Michael"]
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <script>
        console.log('{{ name }}')
    </script>
</html>
```

When I open the console, I see the following:

```
[&#39;Michael&#39;]
```

The ampersand#39 is the [ASCII](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp) character encoding for an apostrophre. If I omit the apostrophes (single quotes) from the console.log statement above (which looks like `console.log({{ name }})`) I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

The strangest thing is when I print the variable anywhere outside the `<script>` tags it works fine.

Any idea what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to take a valid JSON Object/List and use it within javascript use the `tojson` filter within jinja, like this:

```
console.log({{ name|tojson }});
```

the `tojson` filter also marks the value as `safe` so it disable automatic escaping.

Comment: `name` is a list not a dictionary. why are we allowed to use the json filter? and this works for my whether I use `tojson`, `safe`, or both, thanks! is it better to use one or other or both? based on the jinja2 docs it appears `safe` is built into `tojson`

Comment: yes...i think that might be a new additional after i learned this trick ;) technically a list is valid JSON, albeit not normally how we think about it. glad this helped. will update the answer based on using just `tojson`